# Calling AlertDialog.Builder from an Android service

Tags: java, android, adt

I want to display an alert from a `service` and I don't care what activity currently is, just display an alert.

But the builder need construction like

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

But how I know the current activity and pass to the `AlertDialog.Builder`?

Comment: You shouldn't interrupt the user displaying something from the service.

Comment: You should have a look at the answer on this subject
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how I know the current activity and pass to the AlertDialog.Builder?

You dont need to know the current activity. Just start an activity with `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` theme from the service.

Comment: That's fine, but using `Theme.Dialog`, I have an empty dialog with title, is it possible to hide them so I can create `AlertDialog.Builder` inside the `onCreate` of the new activity. THanks.

Comment: No need of the AlertDialog.Builder... set the content of activity..
layout will have a textView and 1-2 buttons..